# How to obtain golden ratio for KOMA article class

Tags: margins, koma-script, article, typearea

I use `\documentclass[11pt,captions=nooneline]{scrartcl}` and I would like to know how I can achieve better margins than default. Apparently, the `typerea` package can help but I find the documentation confusing. How can I obtain a golden margin ratio? What are the best margin choices for scientific articles?

Comment: Most of the scientific articles have fixed templates dictated by the publisher. If you are making your own then `geometry` package is really convenient but needs some manual reading. KOMA should have similar settings too,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing in the European area, KOMA script already provides kind of the golden ratio. Sometimes it looks a little new in the beginning but it is really nice and professional typesetting. I wouldn't change to much manually.

For easy change of margin, at first I would play around with the option `DIV=`. Try values from 10 to 12 for the beginning.

What is happening there and how e.g. to correct the binding side with `BCOR=` or how to in- or exclude the headers, footers and side remarks from the type area can be read in the [KOMA documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).
As an example:

```
\documentclass[%
    ,fontsize=11pt % I believe that is already default
    ,captions=nooneline
    ,DIV=11 % calculation of the typearea
    ,BCOR=12mm % binding correction for the left/inner side
]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
bla blup
\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer to switch the margins or if you have to, the package `geometry` is used widely but I don't use it and therefore am not the right person to explain that. You can have a look on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) of course.